# What is the importance of class function in Swift?

Tags: swift, static-methods

Consider the class bellow:

```
class Downloader {

    class func downloadImageWithURL(url:String) -> UIImage! {
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        return UIImage(data: data!)
    }

}
```

What is the advantages of declare the `downloadImageWithURL` as class method rather than instance method?

Comment: In short: you dont need to make a object if the function is declared as class function. Therefore - saving memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call this **Type Method**, you write

```
Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(...)
```

If it is an **Instance Method**, you need to create a object first:

```
let downloader: Downloader = Downloader()
downloader.downloadImageWithURL(...)
```

In other languages (e.g. C++, Java) you would talk about [static vs. non-static functions](http://www.sitesbay.com/java/java-static-and-non-static-method).

There is no advantage or disadvantages per se, it is an design decision, a very important one! A rule of thumb which came to my mind right now: If there is no need to maintain a state information, go for type methods, otherwise use instance methods.¹

Read more about these methods in [Swift Langauge Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html).

---

¹ At the same time I wrote this rule of thumb, some counter examples came to my mind. So please consider this as a very rough rule of thumb and read some better introductions on object oriented design.

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods work on a concrete instance of the given class, type methods don't.

You cannot call an instance method without a instance, obviously. But it's not just a performance decision, it's more about communicating what the method is or does.

A good rule of thumb is: if you do not access any of the (instance) properties of the class, it probably should be a type method. Factory methods are a good example of type methods, but also anything that is closely related to the class but not tied to an instance.